# .so file not found while importing ruby c extension. (on windows)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have googled a lot and tried many answers but I was not able to find the solution for my issue.

I was trying to install the ruby-ibmdb gem and when I require it, I got an error that .so file is not found but that file was there in that location.

Why ruby is lying to me?

I have placed the .so file in ruby/bin and /lib and many places but it is working.

I have installed devkit and built the .so file my self(Issue maybe because of diff build versions) and

Installed the extension. No issues while installing the gem. But when I require it in the sample program it says .so file cannot be found. (BUt that file is present in the same location)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from connect.rb:2:in `<main>'
        1: from C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- ibm_db (LoadError)
        9: from connect.rb:2:in `<main>'
        8: from C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require'
        7: from C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:130:in `rescue in require'
        6: from C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:130:in `require'
        5: from C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ibm_db-4.0.0-x86-mingw32/lib/ibm_db.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
        4: from C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        3: from C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        2: from C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ibm_db-4.0.0-x86-mingw32/lib/mswin32/ibm_db.rb:90:in `<top (required)>'
        1: from C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': 126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ibm_db-4.0.0-x86-mingw32/lib/mswin32/rb2x/i386/ibm_db.so (LoadError)
```

can anyone help me with this?

Thanks,
Akhil

Comment: Pretty strange, given that Wndows don't use `.so` files, but `.dll` files instead...

Comment: Did you check this issue https://github.com/ibmdb/ruby-ibmdb/issues/83 (and all the related discussion)?

Comment: I have already checked all the related issues in ruby-ibmdb but none of them work for me. As you can see there was no solution give for that issue also

Comment: @Amadan ruby creates .so file using devkit so on windows also it uses .so

Comment: from the dependency walker, I came to know that ibm_db.so is trying to load 64-bit MSVCRT.DLL and KERNAL32.DLL of 64 bit but my .so file is 32 bit. so how what changes will make it pick 32-bit DLL's?